# I made comments function but it doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I made Comment function but it doesn't work. It makes POST packets well but it doesn't make any query to db. So the table is empty.

Below is my source code

CommentController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers; //171029

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->middleware('auth');
        }
        public function store(\App\Http\Requests\CommentsRequest $request, \App\Article $article)
        {
                $comment = $article->comments()->create(array_merge(
                $request->all(), ['user_id'=> $request->user()->id]
                ));
                

                return redirect(route('articles.show', $article->id) .'#comment_'.$comment->id);
        }
}
```

CommentModel

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
        protected $fillable = ['commentable_type', 'commentable_id', 'user_id', 'parent_id', 'content',];

        protected $with = ['user',];

        public function user()
        {
                return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }

        public function commentable()
        {
                return $this->morphTo();
        }

        public function replies()
        {
                return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id')->lastest();
        }

        public function parent()
        {
                return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
        }
```

DataBase (Data in comment Table)

```
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| parent_id        | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| commentable_type | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commentable_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content          | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

It does not have any error.. but doesn't send query... please help me.

Comment: Would you show dump of you request?

Comment: does comments() relationship works correctly? try to manually enter data in database and test the relationship

Answer (score 0):

Mass Assignment
For mass assignment you will need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded`.

```
You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment